# javascript invalid regular expression invalid group

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I spent the whole day trying to fix this regular expression but could not able to know where exactly is the error .

I am using the below in mvc model using regularexpression attributes but when i perform the form valid in my javascript file it's throwing the below error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Invalid group" .

Here is my regular expression.

```
        [Display(Name = "Acct_Email", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Acct_EmailReq")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Acct_EmailLength")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are TLDs with more than 6 characters

Comment: Can you please give a solution for it ?
I have used the same in .net and its working perfectly for email validation . then what went wrong in javascript validation ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you please tell  what exactly is wrong in the above regex ?

Comment: For aa@bb.xx it limits the length of the TLD xx to 6 characters, many are longer: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 0):

At the begining of the regex: `@"^(?("")`, I guess you mean:

```
@"^(?:("")
```

for a non capture group.

Answer (score 0):

@JeSuisCharlie is correct, but he missed one. You also need another colon halfway through. Here is the complete regex with the added colons:

```
^(?:("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~])@))(?:(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$
```

Comment: I am still getting the below error after using the above regex
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:(")(".+?"@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z-!#\$%/_'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~])@))(?:(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$/: Invalid group

Comment: can you please tell me how to use  this mentioned regex in javascript ?